# Excel CountIF and SUMIF

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, countif

I create a table in excel like following:

```
Name  Case  Incoming  Outgoing
name1  ot      5          6
Name2  pr      3          2
name3  rt      4          4
name4  er      2          3
```

I placed a Countif in order to count the names like if i have 5 entries with name1 it will count. The thing is how can i make a sum of all incoming for each name?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: forgot to say that i tried this:

=IF(C:C=H3,SUM(E:E),"")  
where c:c are all my name values column h3 its each name and sum e:e are all incoming values

Comment: Done.. dont worry the answer is 

=SUMIF(C:C,H3,E:E)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please consult the official microsoft support page on **sumif**

```
SUMIF(range, criteria, [sum_range])
```

[visit this page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/sumif-function-HP010062465.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way may be to create a PivotTable, with `Name` for ROWS and Sum of `Incoming` for Σ Values.

However an alternative is to create a unique list of names (you show that already in your example but your question does not make much sense to me unless you have names repeating) say by selecting the `Name` column (assumed to be ColumnA), DATA > Sort & Filter - Advanced, Copy to another location (say N1 in Copy to:) and checking Unique records only.

Then in O2 enter:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,N2,C:C)
```

and copy down to suit.

Another easy way, provided your `Name` column may be sorted, is to sort by that column and then select Columns A:D, DATA > Outline - Subtotal, At each change in:  `Name`, Use function: Sum and check Add subtotal to: `Incoming`.